# How to extract 'strings' from a BMP file?

Tags: node.js, bmp

This may be a general question about BMP files in general...I'm not sure yet. What I'm having difficulty is accessing the source code of these files. I'm tempted to use `translate.google.com` to do this...Oh dear, that would be such a labor, though.

Long short, I'm trying to extract a huge unicode table.

**Edit**

May just skip that method and scrap the html off this [website](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html).

Comment: Oh dear. Did you read the tag description for [tag:bmp]? You may want to use more words to describe what you are trying to achieve (and possibly add why, how, when, et cetera.).

Comment: Probably [this](https://github.com/nowelium/node-bitmap/blob/master/lib/bitmap.js).

Comment: or [this](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)

Comment: My confusion arose from "BMP" being a Unicode term as well as a graphic file format ([Wikipedia Disambiguation Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP)). Now you confirm that you are looking for the image format, I'm only *more* confused. Because that has nothing to do with "Unicode tables"! Or, for that matter, "source code". The source code for a BMP image? The source code for a Unicode table? You thought of 'translating a BMP image'? (And so on. Please use [edit] to clarify.)

Comment: Google translate might be the first choice, but it would simply take too long. https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142483?hl=en

Comment: No, no, I wouldn't recommend this method [lol](http://i.imgur.com/srNnxgL.jpg)

Comment: So you have an *image of some text* and you want to *extract that text* from it. Please [edit] your question and add that. The tag, and mentioning in the question, for Unicode is totally unnecessary for this.

Comment: Well, I think it is relevant. The data from the bmp file is unicode, so it's the object of the project. ?? Perhaps there's an easier way to get what I'm looking for than that described as a hypothesis in my thesis. ?? Most of the time, @Jongware, we don't know the correct questions, even, that's why questions must be formed in a way that it makes the direction of the inquiry most specific.